# How to get the value of a specific field out of cloudformation stack dictionary with python

Tags: python, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I'm using AWS Cloudformation to create a stack and would like to get the value of the '*PublicIP*' field out of the dictionary returned from describe_stacks().
The following schematic code does the work, but it is not resilient to changes in the dictionary structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import boto3
import rest_client

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Bad usage: missing stack name"
    exit(1)

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='profile name')
client = session.client('cloudformation')
response = client.describe_stacks(StackName=sys.argv[1])

try:
    ip = response['Stacks'][0]['Outputs'][1]['OutputValue']
    print "Extracted instance IP address ({0})".format(ip)

except IndexError:
    print "IP address not found"
    exit(1)
```

Is there a more specific API I can use to get this field directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, AWS doesn't support filtering outputs by name. But it's pretty easy to do a filter that will:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import boto3
import rest_client

OUTPUT_KEY = 'InstanceIp'  # <-- Use the proper output name here

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Bad usage: missing stack name"
    exit(1)

stack_name = sys.argv[1]
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='profile name')
cf_resource = session.resource('cloudformation')
stack = cf_resource.Stack(stack_name)

try:
    ip = filter(lambda x: x['OutputKey'] == OUTPUT_KEY, stack.outputs)[0]['OutputValue']
    print "Extracted instance IP address ({0})".format(ip)

except IndexError:
    print OUTPUT_KEY + " not found in " + stack_name
    exit(1)
```

Also, I can assure you that it is future-proof as they never (to my knowledge) update the syntax of their response payloads once the API is officially released.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hopefully you're right about them not changing the APIs, but you know what they say - never say never :)

Comment: :) I was reluctant to say "never", but I really think they would create another endpoint or a boto4 version before attempting to change something like this.